# How to create a odata model for an entity during new instantiation

Tags: sapui5

In CRUD when new button is clicked, how to create a JSON model, based of a entity type.

This empty entity based JSON model can be derived from the metadata entity type and assigned to a view.

I tried to use `Model.onOnMetaDataLoaded` to the get the entity type and use that the default JSON Model with initial values. But I couldn't get the entity type  from the metadata though I can see the entity type in the object.

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel(<ServiceURL>);

oModel.attachMetadataLoaded(null, function(){
   var oMetadata = oModel.getServiceMetadata();
   console.log(oMetadata);
   var metaModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataMetaModel(oMetadata);
   metaModel.getEntityType('XXX') // DOES NOT GIVE VALUE 
},null);
```

`metaModel.getEntityType('XXX') // DOES NOT GIVE VALUE`

And do we need to base our JSON model based off of the entity type when creating new. I am assuming this would be of help in validating data type instead of doing manually.

Comment: `attachMetadataLoaded` might not have triggered yet when you set the metaModel, since it's a callback.

Comment: It was typo(see the updated code)...i was able to debug/see the ometadata, How do you proceed from there to instantiate a model out of the entity type..Do we even do it, this way?

Answer (score 2):

Since you asked, no I don't do it this way... I use the oData model's capabilities to track changes. Any element that supports a binding context can work like this, such as a dialog, a view or a simple form.

In its simplest way, it would look like:

```
myView.setBindingContext(this.getModel().createEntry("/MyEntitySet"));
```

If you want more control, like specify the success- and error handler (and you probably will), it's something like:

```
myView.setBindingContext(this.getModel().createEntry("/MyEntitySet", {
  changeSetId: 'myChanges', 
  properties: {
    myField: 'DefaultValue',
    myDate: new Date()
  },
  success: _ =>  myView.setBusy(false),
  error: _ => myView.setBusy(false)
}));
```

Regarding your question if you need to specify the fields yourself: No you don't, you simply bind any of the values from the entity straight to a field. If the user fills them out, they will appear in the object used in the creation. You can retrieve the object at any time using

```
const filledOutEntityFields = myView.getBindingContext().getObject();
```

In your views you can use a relative binding like you always would:

```
<Input value="{myField}" />
```

Or to be more specific with your types and type checking:

```
<Input value="{
  path: 'myField', 
  type: 'sap.ui.model.type.String',
  constraints: {
    minLength: 1,
    maxLength: 20
  }
}" />
```

And later on you trigger the create. If you used a changeSet, you should pass its name in there.

```
this.getModel().submitChanges('myChanges');
```

One of the advantages is, besides not having to use a JSON model, if you retrieve this data and bind the element with existing results, the code is the same. You can use `submitChanges` on that, too. Except, it sends an update and not a create.

More info: https://ui5.sap.com/sdk#/api/sap.ui.model.odata.v2.ODataModel/methods/createEntry

Comment: thanks. That helps. But would you have to do the validation of the entityType for the number of characters/date / number separately..because the user could input anything and odata fails if the mapping fails before even reaching the service...I see you have define the properties MyField and other  yourself...

Comment: No need to specify any fields, they’re all there. This is simply a way to default certain values like a date. You can set your constraints on the field, like date pickers, min length etc etc just on the XML. Data can also be retrieved from the binding context just like a json model