# What is the proper way to add records to a V2 odata model with two way binding in SAP UI5?

Tags: data-binding, sapui5

I have a SAP UI5 V2 odata model with a two way binding to a table and to a form.

The table is displaying all records, and when clicking on a record, I am using `setBindingContext` to bind the selected table record to the form for editing. When typing in the form, the values dynamically update in the table (because of the two way binding). `model.submitChanges()` writes the change back to the server.

So displaying the list, and editing records in the list are working just fine.

**Now for the problem** How to create records with the same form?

I *also* want to use the same form for adding new records, but I cannot figure out how to unbind the form from a previously selected record, or otherwise create a new blank entry in the data model to be sent to the server.

All of the tutorials I have been able to find on doing UI5 Odata CRUD operations don't really address this problem.

Comment: I wrote something for this a few days ago if you're still looking for examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56924919/how-to-create-a-odata-model-for-an-entity-during-new-instantiation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered [this example](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2) in the documentation which pointed me in the correct direction.

In summary, you use the `oModel.createEntry` method to create a new entry in the oData Model. You then have to bind this new entry to your form with `setBindingContext` - this is the part I was missing.